# How to install drivers for TP LINK WN822N v4 Wireless USB Adapter?

Tags: release-loki, wifi, hardware

I'm new to ubuntu and linux. I recently installed elementary OS a few months ago on my Dell N4050 laptop. It has a built-in wireless adapter which is working fine. I then bought a TP LINK WN822N Wireless USB Adapter but for some reason I can't get it to work.

I have tried the steps mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/625989)

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git cd rtlwifi_new make sudo
make install

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8192cu-dkms
```

However, the steps above did not work for me. I tried going to Settings > Network but did not see another WIFI adapter.

I also tried downloading the drivers from TP Link site [here](http://www.tp-link.com/en/download/TL-WN822N.html#Driver) and downloaded this [driver](http://static.tp-link.com/res/down/soft/TL-WN822N(EU)_V4_160315_Linux.zip). I followed the PDF installation guide included but I get an error during **sudo make**. I don't have the exact error right now as I'm not at home but I can add it here later.

I also tried installing the Driver Manager of Linux Mint to see if it can install the driver. However, it did not work as well.

Appreciate any help on this.

**UPDATE**

I found this [link](https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes/blob/master/README.md) and will give it a try later. Will post updates.

**UPDATE 10-29-2016**

I tried the steps in the link above. Every step succeeded but it seems that the wireless adapter is still not detected even after reboot.

lsub

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0c45:643e Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a5c:21bc Broadcom Corp. BCM2070 Bluetooth 2.1 + EDR
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**UPDATE 10-31-2016**

Recently found out that I'm using TL-WN822N v4 and it seems that it might not yet be supported.

Hopefully drivers will come up in the future.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, finally it works! All I need to do now is get it working as a local hotspot... --------------------- actually, I spoke too soon. The WiFi adaptor worked until I restarted, then it was gone again. Any idea how to resolve this? Thanks

Comment: when i try "modprobe 8192eu" i got the result like this modprobe: FATAL: Module 8192eu not found in directory /lib/modules/4.6.0-kali1-amd64 any body help me ?
how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

This adapter is compatible with the `rtl8192eu` driver, you can install it with the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8192eu-linux-driver
cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8192eu
```

Comment: Mange's github might be better for someone if kernel updates are automatic as Mange has added dkms support

Answer (score 1):

The module is not loading automatically. You can run: `sudo modprobe 8192eu` If it works the adapter, you can add the line `8192eu` 
in the `/etc/modules.conf` file  and try restart.

Answer (score 0):

```
root@mahardika:~# ls -l /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 42 Des  8 08:33 /lib/modules/4.8.0-kali2-686-pae/build -> /usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-kali2-686-pae

root@mahardika:~# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0930:0214 Toshiba Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f3:0235 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
*Bus 002 Device 003: ID 2357:0108*  *(need solution for this problem)*
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 10f1:1a2a Importek Laptop Integrated Webcam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```